# Adding multiple strings in WHERE clause - SQL

Tags: sql, string, addition, where-clause

For the record I am a newbie when it comes to SQL. I am practicing and getting familiar with the syntax, and how it is all structured. I am using [this website](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial) as a crash course in SQL. If you follow the link and take a look at question #5 the directions state to pull up data related only to three countries that of France, Germany, and Italy.

My dilemma is that I do not understand how multiple strings should be structured.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT name, population
FROM world
WHERE name = 'france';
```

The code above will produce a table with both selected columns, and the row that contains France's data, but I still need two other rows with data. However, when I try to edit it to achieve the results I need it won't work:

```
SELECT name, population
FROM world
WHERE name = 'germany' 'france' 'italy';
```

The code above only produces columns and the rows disappear. I need my table to include the name and population of all three countries. I have searched for a simple answer on how to properly add multiple strings and haven't found anything conclusive.

Despite my issue being relatively simple, I still seek help from all y'all, so please help!

Thank you!

Comment: `SELECT name, population FROM world WHERE name IN ( 'germany' , 'france',  'italy');`

Comment: Look at the second example on [Select basics](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_basics).

Answer (score 19):

Try to use `IN` operator, that allows you to make multiple values in `WHERE` clause.

Your code should look like this:

```
SELECT name, population 
FROM   world 
WHERE  name IN ('france','Germany','Italy');
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can put many criteria in a `WHERE` clause. Use `AND` and `OR` to combine them (and parentheses when needed such as in `where a =  1 and (b = 2 or c = 3)`). So your query can be written as

```
SELECT name, population
FROM world
WHERE name = 'germany' OR name = 'france' OR name = 'italy';
```

As has been shown, however, when looking for several values of one attribute you can replace all the ORs with an `IN` clause:

```
WHERE name IN ('germany', 'france', 'italy')
```

which is more readable and hence preferable.

Comment: Thank you so much!